# how to get user email from dropbox login process?

Tags: email, ios5, authentication, dropbox

i'm new for dropbox 1.2, in my app i need to get user email after user login into dropbox, in dropbox 1.0 i've get this value from property "`email`" in `DBAccountInfo.h`, but after i've update into Dropbox 1.2 API, i didnt find that property, can somebody help me how to get that user email info?
thank you

**UPDATE**

i have read Dropbox changelog from 1.0 into 1.1 
"Removed email from DBAccountInfo. This field is being deprecated from the API.
  userId is the recommended way to reference an account."

so we cant get that user email info anymore.

Comment: @Bala can you describe what is that?

Comment: You should post the solution (that it is not possible anymore) as a answer and accept it. (It is fine to answer your own question). So everyone can see that the question is answered.